# animation ends but visual display doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, animation

I am developing a card game in Android, where four players deal their cards turn by turn. A round is of four cards after that I will check who has won this round and the winner of this round will start the next round.

The problem I am facing here is that I can't see the fourth page settling down there in middle. as soon as it ends the animation for the player who deals the card last, it will call the method to check the winner and start next round with the winner player, so every time last page start animation  go to center and disappears without settling down, and call for the next round.

here is my code

in onclick method user will select a card and deal it by pressing a play button, left, right or top button, and runanime and play1 both starts the animation for the particular card

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Second sec = new Second();
    third_turn three = new third_turn();
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String StartingPoint = "";
    try {
        StartingPoint = pref.getString("Start from", "");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "exception on catch" + ex);
    }
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_sort_1:
        String[] sorted = sort(arrPlayer1);
        setup(sorted);
        break;
    case 0:
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgViewArr[0].getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();

        editor.putString("SharedImage", encodetobase64(bitmap));
        editor.putInt("cardno", 0);
        editor.commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) imgViewArr[1].getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        editor2.putString("SharedImage", encodetobase64(bitmap2));
        editor2.putInt("cardno", 1);
        editor2.commit();
        break;
case R.id.btn_play:
        SharedPreferences pref1 = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor_pl = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        int cardno = pref1.getInt("cardno", 0);
        if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.start();
        }

        play1(cardno);

        if (StartingPoint.equals("")) {
            editor_pl.putInt("toset", 0);
            temp[0] = arrPlayer1[cardno];
        }
        if (StartingPoint.equals("start from left")) {
            editor_pl.putInt("toset", 3);
            temp[3] = arrPlayer1[cardno];
        }
        if (StartingPoint.equals("start from top")) {
            editor_pl.putInt("toset", 2);
            temp[2] = arrPlayer1[cardno];
        }
        if (StartingPoint.equals("start from right")) {
            editor_pl.putInt("toset", 1);
            temp[1] = arrPlayer1[cardno];
        }

        editor_pl.commit();

        if (arrPlayer1.length > 1) {
            arrPlayer1 = update(arrPlayer1, cardno);
            play.setEnabled(false);
            setup(arrPlayer1);
        }
        Bottom.setFocusable(false);

        break;
    case R.id.card_left:

        if (StartingPoint.equals("")) {
            temp[1] = Second.bot1(arrPlayer2, temp[0], sir);
            runanime(temp[1], left, 1);
            arrPlayer2 = play(arrPlayer2, temp[1]);
        } else if (StartingPoint.equals("start from top")) {
            temp[3] = third_turn.bot3(arrPlayer2, temp[0], temp[1],
                    temp[2], sir);
            runanime(temp[3], left, 3);
            arrPlayer2 = play(arrPlayer2, temp[3]);
        } else if (StartingPoint.equals("start from right")) {
            temp[2] = third_turn.bot2(arrPlayer2, temp[0], temp[1], sir);
            runanime(temp[2], left, 2);
            arrPlayer2 = play(arrPlayer2, temp[2]);
        }
        left.setFocusable(false);

        break;

    case R.id.card_top:

        if (StartingPoint.equals("")) {
            temp[2] = third_turn.bot2(arrPlayer3, temp[0], temp[1], sir);
            runanime(temp[2], top, 2);
            arrPlayer3 = play(arrPlayer3, temp[2]);
        } else if (StartingPoint.equals("start from left")) {
            temp[1] = Second.bot1(arrPlayer3, temp[0], sir);
            runanime(temp[1], top, 1);

            arrPlayer3 = play(arrPlayer3, temp[1]);
        } else if (StartingPoint.equals("start from right")) {
            temp[3] = third_turn.bot3(arrPlayer3, temp[0], temp[1],
                    temp[2], sir);
            runanime(temp[3], top, 3);
            arrPlayer3 = play(arrPlayer3, temp[3]);
        }
        top.setFocusable(false);

        break;
    case R.id.card_right:

        if (StartingPoint.equals("")) {
            temp[3] = third_turn.bot3(arrPlayer4, temp[0], temp[1],
                    temp[2], sir);
            runanime(temp[3], right, 3);
            arrPlayer4 = play(arrPlayer4, temp[3]);
        } else if (StartingPoint.equals("start from left")) {
            temp[2] = third_turn.bot2(arrPlayer4, temp[0], temp[1], sir);
            runanime(temp[2], right, 2);
            arrPlayer4 = play(arrPlayer4, temp[2]);
        } else if (StartingPoint.equals("start from top")) {
            temp[1] = Second.bot1(arrPlayer4, temp[0], sir);
            runanime(temp[1], right, 1);
            arrPlayer4 = play(arrPlayer4, temp[1]);
        }
        right.setFocusable(false);
        break;
    }

}
```

the runanime method: according to string I will know which card I have to use for animation. the last parameter is to know where to set that card in middle.

```
private void runanime(String card, ImageView from, int to) {

Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) from.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    editor.putString("SharedImage", encodetobase64(bmp));
    editor.putInt("toset", to);
    editor.commit();
    
    ViewParent view = from.getParent();
    sp.play(soundIds[0], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    ((View) view).startAnimation(animMove);
    
}

private void runanime(String card, ImageView from, int to) {

Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) from.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
    editor.putString("SharedImage", encodetobase64(bmp));
    editor.putInt("toset", to);
    editor.commit();
    
    ViewParent view = from.getParent();
    sp.play(soundIds[0], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    ((View) view).startAnimation(animMove);
    
}
```

now in OnAnimationEnd method I retrieve those value which I had set in shared preferences and set that images in middle, and store them as a string in temp array to know the winner.

```
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Bitmap bmp = decodetobase64(pref.getString("SharedImage", ""));
    Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
    int toset = pref.getInt("toset", 0);
    //String StartingPoint = pref.getString("Start from", "");

        switch (toset) {
        case 0:
            mid_1.setImageDrawable(image);
            flag1 = true;
            top.setFocusable(true);
            top.performClick();
            break;
        case 1:
            mid_2.setImageDrawable(image);
            flag2 = true;
            right.setFocusable(true);
            right.performClick();
            break;
        case 2:
            mid_3.setImageDrawable(image);
            flag3 = true;
            Bottom.setFocusable(true);
            play.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case 3:
            mid_4.setImageDrawable(image);
            flag4 = true;
            break;
}
if (flag1 && flag2 && flag3 && flag4) {
        NextPlayer(temp);
    }

}
```

here after setting a mid_4  the flag4  sets to true and the if loop starts executing, but visually I can't see the fourth card settling down. I even tried to use a thread.sleep method but its not coming handy. so please can anyone tell me what to do?

it seems like in OnAnimationEnd method flag4 becomes true before image to set in mid_4.

Comment: animMove is a initializer for xml file of animation